# node-red error: "Error stopping node: Error: [BaseClient:disconnect] Client is not connected" AND "Error: Connection refused: Not authorized"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, iot, node-red, ibm-cloud-tools

I am following this tutorial on how to send a picture taken from the pi camera to the CLoudant NoSQL database on Bluemix.

"There are 3 node-red flows in total. The Process Doorbell flow (on the raspberry pi) should send an IBM IoT visitorAlert event message to Node-RED on Bluemix which should, in turn, send an IBM IoT sendPicture command message back to Node-RED on Raspberry Pi.  This will eventually create a Base64 encoded image string, package it up with the filename, length and status into a payload that gets sent to Cloudant in Bluemix by the insertPicture node.  See if it worked by going to the Bluemix Cloudant dashboard."

I created the flows on node-Red, but am getting this error on the node-red in the pi:

> "Error stopping node: Error: [BaseClient:disconnect] Client is not
>   connected"

I am getting this error on the node-red in Bluemix:

> "Error: Connection refused: Not authorized"

What could be the issue?

Comment: If you will provide your 6 character org ID for the IoT service, we can check the logs for authorization errors.  Also would be helpful if you include link to the tutorial you are following.

Comment: You should include your flows and how you configured the nodes to authorize.